# excel formula to return multiple results

Tags: excel

I am currently using Index,Match to match records from one sheet to the other. Works great, except when I have multiple records with the same identifier. Let me explain:

The sheet named Open Leave Report contains the raw data (lookup values), while the sheet named Open Leave Capture contains the scrubbed data. So my formula looks like this

```
=INDEX('Open Leave Report'!O:O,MATCH('Open Leave Capture'!C9,'Open Leave Report'!B:B,0))
```

Works great, except when I have the following:

```
Column B    Column O
Employee ID Continuous or Intermittent
1646484     Intermittent
1646484     Continuous
```

So when I type the Employee ID in the Open Leave Capture it always brings back the first row, but it ignores the second record. It looks like this:

```
Employee ID   Type
1646484       Intermittent
1646484       Intermittent
```

Is there any way I can format my Index/Match formula to bring back both records?

I hope I explained this well

Answer (score 1):

Don't use INDEX and MATCH for this...use PivotTables instead.

Whenever I want certain records from a list to appear in a different place, I turn my source data into an Excel Table, and make a PivotTable out of it, and then filter that PivotTable to show just the items I'm interested in.

No formulas, and as soon as you refresh the PivotTable it will automatically pick up any changes to your source data. Unlike formulas, which can be overwhelmingly complex to pick apart, and rely on you remembering to drag the formula down the page in order to ensure you capture any new data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is far simpler if you convert the source data into a table. Select the source data then use Insert > Table.

This solution has the following assumptions:

1. Source data has columns named "Employee ID" and "Type"
2. In the destination, the IDs to be looked up start from cell A2
3. In the destination, the values to be returned start from cell B2

This is formula to put into cell B2. This is an array formula. You need to double click into the cell, paste the formula, then save it by pressing `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`. You can then fill it down as far as you need to go.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Type],SMALL(IF(Table1[Employee ID]=A2,ROW(Table1[Employee ID])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Employee ID]])),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))),"Not that many")`